# AWS ACL/WAF - How to Change Rule Priority?

Tags: amazon-web-services, acl, amazon-waf

I have a WAF ACL associated with my application load balancer and I'd like to change the priority of the rules. For the life of me I can't find any documentation on how this is done and can't figure out how to adjust the priority in the AWS UI. Is this possible or do I have to recreate my ACL from scratch in a different order?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you don't have to recreate your rules again.

You can do the following:

1. Click on the rule you want to change priority.
2. Then click on edit, you will be directed to Rule builder to edit your rule.
3. Click save, if you don't want to change any options.
4. Then, you be directed to Set Rule Priority where you can change rule priority.
5. Click save and it's done.